# How to put page numbers in PDF using NVelocity

Tags: c#, pdf, nvelocity, page-numbering

I am using `NVelocity` to create PDF in C#.NET. My question is how to number the pages in the produced PDF document in code.

The number of pages is not predefined, and the numbering should appear on the bottom of the page in the format `page 1 of 10`.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you got things mixed up. NVelocity is a *text* templating library, it has nothing to do with PDFs.